# How can I create function which will return value of jQuery method attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html structure:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="img/product1.png" alt="product1"></li>
        <li><img src="img/product2.png" alt="product2"></li>
        <li><img src="img/product3.png" alt="product3"></li>
        <li><img src="img/product4.png" alt="product4"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I have done attempt create function which will get attribute of current img element and I want to return from this function this current attribute, I have next code:

```
var sr = "";
function imgSrc(){
   $('div').on("click", "ul li img", function () {
        sr = $(this).attr("src");
        return sr;
    });
}

console.log(imgSrc());
```

unfortunately I get undefined in my console.

Comment: You need to click on the element to get its attribute. This is what your code means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything. It just defines an onClick handler. So that's why you get a return value of 'undefined'

If your intention is to log the src of a div when you click on it, your code would need to be more like this...

```
$('div').on("click", "ul li img", function () 
{
    var sr = $(this).attr("src");
    console.log(sr);
});
```

That registers the event listener on the element.

However, if you want to wrap the listener in a function and then call that function, as you have done, that will also work - the function in the on("click") will be triggered when clicking an element. The value of sr will be set, but the outer function itself won't return a value. You would need to find another way to do something with the value of sr, within the function in the on("click")

Comment: Thank you great for your advice, but I need really this solution not only for log, I would want to separate my code with function help, because I think it's more beautiful when I have separate method in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you must put your event handler before calling function

```
var sr = "";
function imgSrc(obj){
    if(obj.tagName == "IMG")
        sr = $(obj).attr("src");
    else
        sr = $(obj).find("img").attr("src");
    return sr;
}
$('div').on("click", "li img", function () {
    console.log(imgSrc(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you want sr to have the attribute value?

```
var sr = "";
$('div').on("click", "ul li img", function () {
    sr = $(this).attr("src");
});

console.log(sr);
```